# No $_POST data in callback from PayPal

Tags: php, paypal, nvp

I'm integrating Standard PayPal payment via NVP. I've created everything, but my problem is that on my complete page PayPal doesn't return any $_POST and $_GET data. Even, so I put `rm=2` in my request to PayPal.  That's totally odd. As I have checked my old PP integration as that also doesn't return any data. But I have checked it only on my localhost. Any idea? As that seems to me for PayPal issues.

Part of my call to PP NVP below:

```
'PWD' => $password, 
'USER' => $user, 
'SIGNATURE' => $signature,
'METHOD' => $method
'BUTTONTYPE' => 'BUYNOW',
'BUTTONCODE' => 'HOSTED',
'BUTTONSUBTYPE' => 'PRODUCTS',
'BUTTONCOUNTRY' => 'GB',
'BUTTONIMAGEURL' => 'https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/btn/btn_buynow_107x26.png',
'L_BUTTONVAR1' => 'return=' . $this->getReturnUrl(),
'L_BUTTONVAR2' => 'notify_url=' . $this->getNotifyUrl(),
'L_BUTTONVAR3' => 'invoice=' . $this->getInvoice(),
'L_BUTTONVAR4' => 'currency_code=GBP',
'L_BUTTONVAR5' => 'item_number=1',
'L_BUTTONVAR6' => 'item_name=' . $this->getItemName(),
'L_BUTTONVAR7' => 'amount=' . $this->getAmount(),
'L_BUTTONVAR8' => 'cpp_header_image=' . $this->getHeaderImage(),
'L_BUTTONVAR9' => 'rm=2', // return data by POST method
```

Comment: Look at your server access logs to see whether PP is calling the script you expect.  Also execute `echo file_get_contents('php://input')` to get the raw data sent by PayPal

Comment: I have checked raw data as well. There is nothing. I'm assuming that can be something with PayPal side. I have tried and checked everything. The code is fine. I have checked PayPal account setting and there are all fine as well.

Comment: What are you getting at the return URL?  POST or GET data? It seems Paypal made breaking changes recently - I don't think they have fully communicated these.  Forms that used to work now do not.

Comment: Now, is even worst as I'm getting: Error message like this one: Sorry. We're not able to process your request. Please try again later.

Comment: I reckon that PayPal developers need to messing around NVP. As I have been getting different banch of errors. Even when I haven't changed anything in my code, I still was getting different errors.